# Using Handlebars for conditional CSS

Tags: handlebars.js

In the snippet below I'd expect row a to have the class new-entry and row c to have the class moving-up but neither does.

I'm certain this is a silly mistake but I can't see it

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("newEntry", function() {
    return this.newEntry ? 'class="new-entry"' : '';
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("movingUp", function() {
    return this.movingUp ? 'class="moving-up"' : '';
});

var source = document.getElementById('leaderboard-template').innerHTML; 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
var outlet = document.getElementById('outlet');

  outlet.innerHTML = template({leaders: [
    {name: 'a', signature_count: 10, newEntry: true},
    {name: 'b', signature_count: 8},
    {name: 'c', signature_count: 6, movingUp: false},
  ]});
```

```css
.new-entry {
  background-color:red;
}
.moving-up {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="leaderboard-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
  <table>
      <thead> 
          <th>Constituency</th> 
          <th>Votes</th> 
      </thead> 
      <tbody> 
          {{#leaders}} 
          <tr {{newEntry}}> 
              <td>{{name}}</td> 
              <td><span {{movingUp}}>{{signature_count}}</span></td> 
          </tr> 
          {{/leaders}} 
      </tbody> 
  </table> 
</script>

<div id="outlet"></div>
```

Comment: I click on stackoverflow's `Run code snippet` button and look at the output in the browser's F12 tool. The class is set, actually but all quotes are rewritten as `&quot;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebar converts the return value of a helper to an HTML escaped string. Use `Handlebars.SafeString` like this if you don't want that:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("newEntry", function() {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString( this.newEntry ? 'class="new-entry"' : '' );
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("movingUp", function() {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString( this.movingUp ? 'class="moving-up"' : '' );
});
```